# How can I partition my disk?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, apfs

I have a `macOS Mojave (10.14.2)` and I would like create a 20 GB `MS-DOS (FAT)` partition on my 128 GB `APFS` disk.

But `Disk Utility` constantly gives me an error:

[image]

My Time Machine is turned off:

[image]

My FileVault is turned off:

[image]

**I also tried the followings:**

1. `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999` command to delete snapshots.
2. `First Aid` in Disk Utility, then restarted with `Command + S` and typed `/sbin/fsck -fy` in terminal. In both cases it said that my disk appears to be OK.
3. Tried to boot in Safe mode (`Command + Shift`) then start partitioning.
4. Tried to restart with `Command + R` then partition from `Disk Utility`.

The problem is the same with `Boot Camp Assistant`, if I try to install Windows 10.

[image]

**Why on Earth Apple prevents their users to use another operating system next to macOS? Is this a nefarious business tactics? Because it seems not to have solution at all while having an APFS disk!**

Answer (score 1):

Okay I solved the problem. First I created a backup, because everything got erased!

1. I restarted my MacBook in Recovery mode (Command + R)
2. Went to the `Disk Utility`
3. Clicked on my SSD that was in `APFS`
4. Clicked on Erase, and chose `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` with `GUID Partition Map`
5. After it was done, went back to the previous menu in Recovery mode and clicked to Reinstall Mac OS
6. I chose the new disk to install macOS (it took me around 30-60 minutes)

After installing macOS you can set your previous Time Machine backups. Finally I'm done, and now it enables me to partition my disk.

The problem was the `APFS` didn't enabled me to partition, only `HFS+`.

**But be careful:** since `APFS` is now the standard filesystem on Apple devices and if it has some important advantages which is not supported by `HFS+` you will be messed up.

Take a look at `APFS` advantages before you choose.

Although you can reset your disk back to `APFS` anytime you want, but you might miss the ability of partitioning.

I think if you want to keep your drive as `APFS` you can purchase an external hard drive (it doesn't cost so much, but indeed needs extra care if you are working with a laptop).

**Edit:** After I erased my SSD with `HFS+`, I tried to erased it with `APFS` once again. (the whole SSD) And this time, it enabled me to partition in `APFS`. :)